# Substring exception?

Tags: ios, substring

I'm trying to perform an action to every single character in a string.  But I keep getting an error that doesn't make sense:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '-[__NSCFString substringWithRange:]: Range {2, 3} out of bounds; string length 4'
```

how is {2, 3} out of bounds?
thanks!

Comment: Yep, 2 + 3 >= 4, therefore exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NSRange isn't {start, end}, it's {start, length}. Range {2, 3} includes characters 2, 3, and 4 of the string.. which, with length 4, only has characters at indexes 0, 1, 2, and 3.

If you're iterating over single-character substrings, you may want to try using `enumerateSubstringsInRange:options:usingBlock:` with the `NSStringEnumerationByComposedCharacterSequences` option, instead of making the ranges yourself. This will give you correct behavior even for variable-sized "characters" like composed sequences and high-unicode surrogate pairs (e.g. emoji.)

Comment: Thanks!  I actually thought it was {start, end}